# Regex to find words (hash) with numbers and letters

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of strings and some of them has "words" with numbers and letters, for example:

> Revert Push Diamond tick mark classes to Eclipse This reverts commit 4086b8666cdc839b5ec7e7bfff0ae1b9695542ff .......

Is there some regex expression to remove these words (hash)?

Comment: Yes, but you need to be able to tell us how many characters long those hashes are - presumably they contain only characters `0-9a-f` if they're a hex representation of something - so that's the first part.

Comment: So your expected output would be `4086b8666cdc839b5ec7e7bfff0ae1b9695542ff` ?  Are the hashes all the same length in the file?

Answer (score 1):

You could look for sequences of hex characters delimited with whitespace of a required length, e.g. between `30` and `50` characters. For example:

```
import re

text = """Revert Push Diamond tick mark classes to Eclipse This reverts commit 
4086b8666cdc839b5ec7e7bfff0ae1b9695542ff .......
Another test
48a8b89d9f8e80a938f8ab487de09ff
"""

for hash in re.findall(r'\s+([0-9a-fA-F]{30,50})\s+', text):
    print(hash)
```

Would display:

```
4086b8666cdc839b5ec7e7bfff0ae1b9695542ff
48a8b89d9f8e80a938f8ab487de09ff
```